# Grammar for homotopy type theory?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, type-theory, programming, homotopy-type-theory

The HoTT book says:

> We will not attempt to give a formal presentation of the grammar of a
> valid inductive definition and its resulting induction and recursion
> principles and pattern matching rules. This is possible to do (indeed,
> it is necessary to do if implementing a computer proof assistant), but
> provides no additional insight. With practice, one learns to
> automatically deduce the induction and recursion principles for any
> inductive definition, and to use them without having to think twice.

So I'm on the lookout for an EBNF or PEG grammar that describes the syntax of everything in HoTT book.  Is there one out there?  Is it even possible to write one down?  Because I got stuck implementing $\mathcal{U}_i$ (the $i$th universe) as a class in Python.  Since $i:\Bbb{N}$ yet $\Bbb{N}: \text{Type}$ and $\text{Type} : \mathcal{U}_i$ for some $i$.  So what you get is a circular import error that is AFAICT not possible to get rid of.

So a grammar might lend some advice on structuring the Python encoding of the theory as well.

Comment: If you are using explicit universes then you should not be using the $\textsf{Type}$ notation, because it is ambiguous. ($\textsf{Type}$ stands for $\mathcal{U}_i$ for some $i$ that is to be inferred from the context.) Furthermore the $i$ subscript is not an “internal” natural number but rather a “meta” natural number.

Comment: There's no intrinsic difference between the notations $\mathsf{Type}$ and $\mathcal{U}$; you can just as well write $\mathsf{Type}_i$ to be explicit or $\mathcal{U}$ to be ambiguous.

Comment: As for your question, as suggested in the text you quoted, you might want to check out the implementation of any proof assistant.  One simple one from a few years ago is http://math.andrej.com/2012/11/08/how-to-implement-dependent-type-theory-i/.

Comment: @MikeShulman I don't know OCaml nor Haskell.   Was wanting to prototype in Python.  It seems like if you used Haskell, most of the work is already done for you which is nice.

Comment: @MikeShulman that article does help me understand the syntax more.  So thank you!

Comment: @MikeShulman what if I wanted mostly no abuses of notation in my system.   Then shouldn't I go with $U(0), U(1), \dots$?  So you're saying I should just do `Universe = Type` where `Type` is a class (a type) in Python?

Comment: Well, I would say that when a system is fully formalized (such as by implementing it in a computer) there cannot, by definition, be any "abuses of notation" -- whatever used to be an "abuse of notation" and still remains has to have been made precise to be permitted by the formalization, and hence is no longer abusive but permitted.  For instance, Coq allows writing simply "Type" to mean an unspecified universe, but this isn't an abuse because its semantics are precisely defined by Coq's universe inference mechanism.

Comment: However, it's indeed certainly much simpler to require your universes to come with an explicit indexing.  Without knowing exactly what you're doing in Python I can't comment on how you should encode universes there; ordinarily when coding a proof assistant the types and terms of the object-language would both be _elements_ of some "expression type" in the host language.